# Using Symmetry for finding volume

Tags: volume, multiple-integral

I have a confusion regarding the symmetry of the volume in the following question.

Find the volume common to the sphere $x^2+y^2+z^2=16$ and cylinder $x^2+y^2=4y$.

The author used polar coordinates $x=rcos\theta$ snd $y=rsin\theta$ and does something like this:

Required volume $V=4\int_0^{π/2}\int_0^{4sin\theta}(16-r^2)^{1/2}rdrd\theta$. The reason for multiplying by $4$ is the symmetry of the solid w.r.t. $xy$-plane.

My point of  confusion is that this solid cannot be cut into $4$ identical parts, so how it can be multiplied by $4$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> My point of confusion is that this solid cannot be cut into 4 identical parts

Sure it can.

The sphere is centered at the origin, and the axis of the cylinder (which has radius $2$) intersects $(0,2)$ in the $x-y$ plane.

Slice it in half with the $z=0$ plane.  Then slice it again with the $x=0$ plane.

These are reflected in the limits of integration.

Comment: @John...Thanks a lot. I got my mistake of overlooking angle $\theta$ equal to π which is actually double of the actual value. Indeed, the origin plays a vital role in finding limits.

Answer (score 2):

A picture is useful here. The solid can indeed be split into four symmetric segments, as shown in the following surface plot.

[image]

Comment: @Erik...Thanks a lot for this beautiful picture. It is really helpful in giving wings to my imagination.

Answer (score 0):

Before that what happened to the latitude $\phi$ ?

The picture shows a situation  [Viviani](https://www.google.co.in/search?hl=en&site=imghp&tbm=isch&source=hp&biw=1028&bih=521&q=viviani&oq=viviani&gs_l=img.1.1.0l10.17336.288445.0.294391.7.6.0.1.1.0.301.884.1j2j1j1.5.0....0...1ac.1.64.img..1.6.882.cyztkXn1ow8#hl=en&tbm=isch&q=viviani%20curve&imgrc=Hco1VRRWuweGzM%3A)  suitable for what you described.

Two fold symmetry is evident as also factor 4.

Comment: @Narasimham...I really dn't understand what these pictures have to do with my problem.

Answer (score 0):

The volume can be cut into 4 identical parts. See that both volume are simetric for each quadrant. That's why the angle variation is from $0$ to $\pi/2$.